# Adequate statistical method to compare objective measure vs estimations

Tags: anova, experiment-design, bias, hypothesis-testing

I am using a software for image recognition to do the following:
calculate the percentage of a surface that is painted black.
On the other hand, there are several observers that estimate the percentage of the same surface that is painted black. I'm interested in calculating the error introduced by the "subjective" method, i.e the observers and their estimations.
So, I have multiple surfaces, the value provided by the software for each surface, and the estimations from the observers.$$\\$$
How can I, statistically, prove that the subjective method is poor in comparison with the software?
[image: Data Example]

Comment: can you consider the software response to be the ground truth, precise beyond doubt? and in that case, why are you trying to prove something that's already stated?

Comment: and, by surface, do you mean an actual solid surface that someone has taken a picture of?

Comment: In this case, we will be considering the software response as the "true value". The comparison is because we want to show the outperformance of the software use with respect to the observational method. Therefore we want to show that the observational method is both imprecise and inaccurate. By "surface" yes, it is a surface that we have a picture of, for example, a wall.

Comment: If the definition of poor is imprecise ("the subjective method is producing estimates all over the place"), there is no need to run any statistical test - any descriptive statistics or visualisation that shows the estimates are indeed all over the place would do. If the definition of poor is inaccurate ("the subjective method is systematically overestimating the area that is painted black by x%"), then depending on how far you want to go, you may need anything between a simple t-test for each surface to hierarchical models to estimate the subjective method's bias.